# The URI is not accessible when creating remote URL connection - Oracle MAF

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, ssl-certificate, oracle-maf

We have recently needed to change our SSL certificate on our server. Our consuming application has suddenly stopped working. I had presumed this was to do with Java's cacerts, and modified the program to import the new certificate to each client, the problem was not resolved.

When the application attempts to load the remote view (shown below) on the server, it simply loads a white page. I have tried loading the page through http:// and it seems to function, however the rest of the application (including the API) requires https, and subsequent calls to the API fail (images loaded through https are showing as broken within the app).

[image: remote uri is not accessible]

The website is functional, and when I access URL's being provided to the app, through my desktop browser they load without issue. The app is also functional when I run it in Debug mode, these issues only occur when I use the "Run" build mode.

I have tried creating a blank MAF application, hoping it was some caching issue, however this new app also cannot load the remote URI. I have done a clean build and have tested other remote URI's (they work). I feel as if there is an issue with Java somehow not accepting the new certificate. The first time I tried to load the website within Eclipse's browser, an error displayed along the lines of "certificate revocation information". I didn't pay much attention to this error and it provided the option to install the new certificate, after which the page loaded within eclipse's browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:**

There was no chain installed, I installed the provided ca-bundle file and updated the httpd.conf file to reflect the chain location and the app now works.

**Long answer**:

When our server dev installed the new certificate, he neglected to install the ca-bundle (certificate chain) provided by the CA. The site was working in a browser, I can only assume, because it has a more complete list of trusted CA's built in. My best guess is that MAF requires the chain to be installed and was failing some security test, or the chrome webview it uses did not have this CA on the trusted list.

Answer (score 0):

In Jdeveloper there is an option of **Disabling the Application Transport Security** as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8RMV.png).

Could you try disabling in your eclipse too, Kindly refer this doc https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL, this might do a little help :)

The issue seems to be due to the changed SSL certificate on your server.

Comment: I may not have been clear that this only seemed to be a problem on Android. I'm not quite sure how disabling ATS would have helped either when I need encryption. Perhaps I'm not understanding what ATS is. Either way I solved the problem, thank you for your input though.